# Whats the best way to add a dataset of 50 Folders to an iOS App?

Tags: ios, filesystems

In my case I have 50 Folders where each of it has subfolders and images. I could drag them into the apps main bundle but there are many duplicate filenames and it would be more practical to access them in the structured way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording "it would be more practical to access them in the structured way" seems to suggest that you think the `Resources` folder cannot contain a folder tree of files, it can. However if you let Xcode itself copy your resource files into the bundle it will flatten the tree without any option to preserve it (for reasons unknown). To address this you can copy the files into the bundle using a build script.

In outline, you need to fill in the gaps with some reading:

1. First add your files and folders into your project. Use one group per folder, in Xcode 9 creating a group creates a corresponding folder in the project directory but in prior versions you must create the group and then associate it with a folder – check the documentation of whatever Xcode version you are using.
2. Mark all the folders and files added in this way as **not** part of your build target. This prevents Xcode copying the files automatically into the bundle, and flattening your folder tree in the process.
3. Now in the target settings go to the "Build Phases" tab and add a new build script phase. Add a shell script which uses something like `ditto` to copy the folder tree into the bundle. Various environment variables are set which reference the project and the bundle, check your Xcode documentation or just run a dummy script and dump them out (it is an option, or use `printenv`). You can use these environment variables to determine the source and destination for your copy.
4. In your app itself you can locate the root folder of your tree using standard bundle methods. From there you can use whatever method you choose to traverse it/reference items with in it, in exactly the same way you would if the folder tree was not inside the bundle.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I already tried to do this without the script-trick. My goal is to use NSFileManager after loacating the bundle path to traverse it, like i would do on macOS. I will try to write the script, still it doesn't feel right to do it in a complicated way (thought it would be easy). Probably it is restricted/not commonly implemented because of iOS sandboxing?

Comment: @matthiaswitt - It's not related to sandboxing. For some unknown reason Xcode's standard copy of items into a bundle flattens any folder tree without any option to preserve it. People have raised it as an issue for years. One group effected are library/framework writers who wish to structure the included header files, as Apple themselves might do. However it is addressable with a short build script, which isn't really "complicated", and we can only guess that that is Apple's rationale for not building it in.